# How to rowfilter by ID on devexpress vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I need to filter LOTID value from my database but my rowfilter is not functioning on devexpress gridview.

Database Column Name is LOTID , example of row value of LOTID is  L-S3FH2

My code is as below :

```
Protected Sub ClipData()

      ......... 

       connx.Close()

        'Dim RowLotID As String = DetailGridx.GetRowValues("LotID").ToString

        Dim dv2 As DataView = New DataView(dt1)

        'dv2.RowFilter = "LOTID = 'L-" + RowLotID + "'"

        DetailGridx.DataSource = dv2
        DetailGridx.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Please guide me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using string formatting like this: `dv2.RowFilter = String.Format("LOTID='{0}'", "L-" & RowLotID)`? How does `DataView` not functioning in ASPxGridView data binding?

Comment: sorry my mistake, dataview is functioning, just the rowfilter is not functioning, the detailGridx.GetRowValues("LOTID") there return error Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: *Input string was not in a correct format* usually occurs when involving string parsing (e.g. string to integer). In which line the error above exactly thrown and is that `LOTID` has string data type in gridview?

Comment: The error appeared in ' Dim RowLotID As String = DetailGridx.GetRowValues("LOTID").ToString' and yes, example for LOTID's value is L-S3FH2

Error Shown: 
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "LOTID" to type 'Integer' is not valid.]

Comment: Is that `LOTID` is a key value for the grid (set by `KeyFieldName`)? I found that you're using `GetRowValues` with wrong overload.

Comment: yes, it is set in my ASPxGridView  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="DetailGridx" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ClientInstanceName="DetailGridx"  KeyFieldName="LOTID>

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GetRowValues.method), `ASPxGridView.GetRowValues()` overload should be like this:

```
Public Function GetRowValues( 
   ByVal visibleIndex As Integer,  
   ByVal fieldNames As String[] 
) As Object
```

The first parameter is an `Integer`, hence current overload usage is wrong since you're passing string to `visibleIndex` parameter.

You should use visible index from `EventArgs` as first argument (`VisibleIndex` property value is an `Integer`) and mention column name in second argument like this:

```
Dim RowLotID As String = DetailGridx.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "LotID").ToString()
```

Or use `KeyFieldName` property from `ASPxGridView` ID:

```
Dim RowLotID As String = DetailGridx.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, DetailGridx.KeyFieldName).ToString()
```

Then you can use string formatting for `RowFilter` filter string:

```
Dim dv2 As DataView = New DataView(dt1)
dv2.RowFilter = String.Format("LOTID='{0}'", "L-" & RowLotID)
```

Comment: you mean put visible index to the LOTID gridview column? sorry but i dont really get the meaning of this line The first parameter is an Integer, hence current overload usage is wrong since you're passing string to visibleIndex parameter.

You should use visible index from EventArgs as first argument (VisibleIndex property value is an Integer) and mention column name in second argument like this:

Comment: No, the `VisibleIndex` property added to tell which data item (i.e. row index) currently read, it depends on `EventArgs`. The `LotID` is column name which you want to read current row value.

Comment: oh i see, but there is another error thrown e.VisibleIndex is not a member of 'EventArgs'

Comment: You can use any `Integer` value as replacement to `e.VisibleIndex` for first parameter, or use index from `For` loop (`For i = 0 To [max grid index])` as in documentation example.

Comment: ahh, sorry for bothering you again, another error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for this line Dim RowLotID As String = DetailGridx.GetRowValues(0, DetailGridx.KeyFieldName).ToString, or is there any other way to perform rowfilter for this?

Comment: Make sure that `ASPxGridView` bound to data source properly (see [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18183/why-might-paging-sorting-grouping-filtering-not-work-in-the-aspxgridview)). If the data has bound properly, then `DetailGridx.GetRowValues` should return expected value.

Comment: i have declared visibleindex on gridview column and used for loop, still the same outcome.

Comment: still the same outcome, but once i removed the filter no error appeared.

Comment: I want to know where you call this `ClipData` method, is it called inside grid view event handler? NRE occurs if the `visibleIndex` contains -1 or the row which called by `GetRowValues` contains null value. Can you show how you're using for-loop to call every row index?

Comment: sorry for the extremely late reply, i have replaced it with oncustomcallback function, filter using e.parameters and it works. anyway Thanks.